find -type f -iregex '\.\/INPUT.*\.(mp4|avi)$' returns nothing, why?
I am on: GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
I'm trying to get a list of all my video files with the extension .mp4 and .avi, my understanding with regular expression and follow up searches suggest to do it this way and I've used (this|to|make|lists) for loops before that worked fine.
So why does this return nothing:
find -type f -iregex '\.\/INPUT.*\.(mp4|avi)$'

This returns all MP4 files:
find -type f -iregex '\.\/INPUT.*\.mp4$'


See my answer to the linked duplicate. Your current pattern should work with -regextype posix-extended. Xor modify the pattern:-iregex '\.\/INPUT.*\.\(mp4\|avi\)$'.

Note: the fact you're using GNU bash is not really important. The fact you're using GNU find is important (other implementations may or may not support -regextype). I assumed you're using GNU find. Please write a comment if your find is not GNU find. The output of find --version will include GNU if it's GNU find.

With BSD find, you'd use find -E (analogous to grep -E, sed -E, etc) instead of -regextype posix-extended.
